# Python Django Subcategory

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to print the subcategory names of each Main Category. The below code is now showing all subcategories for every Main category. How can I do?

*index.html*

```
{% for mainCatList in main_cat_list %}
    <li class="subMenu"><a>{{ mainCatList.main_category_name }}</a>
        <ul>
        {% for subCat in cat_list %}
            <li><a href="products.html"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>{{ subCat.category_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

*views.html*

```
from django.shortcuts import render                          
from .models import Product, Category, Main_Category


def homePageView(request):

    main_cat_list = Main_Category.objects.all()
    cat_list = Category.objects.all()

    context = {'main_cat_list': main_cat_list, 'cat_list': cat_list}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: What's the relationship between Main_Category and Category models? show your models.py file.

Comment: If you have an one to many rel between MainCat and Category models then  you can do like `{% for mainCat in main_cat_list %} {% for subCat in mainCat.cat_list %}{{subCat.name}}{% endfor %}{% endfor %}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The perfect solution will be in the nested for loop as below:

{% for sub_cat in main_cat.category_set.all %} {% endfor %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your Category has foreign key to Main_Catagory. In that case, you can do this

```
{% for main_cat in main_cat_list %}
<li class="subMenu"><a>{{ main_cat.main_category_name }}</a>
    <ul>
        {% for sub_cat in main_cat.category_set.all %}
        <li><a href="products.html"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>{{ sub_cat.category_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I already have figured out this solution earlier. Forgot to share. This worked fine. Thanks for your response.